# How can I do a loop on include_tasks or many tasks, and the condition is a variable when write ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have tried:

```
- name: set passed
  set_fact:
      i: 0
- name: test
  include_tasks: test2.yml
  until: i == 3
```

in test2.yml:

```
- name: set i
  set_fact:
    i: '{{ i|int + 1 }}'
```

But seems the "until" can't be used on include_tasks, only can be used on single task, but I need to loop a set of tasks.

Then I tried some thing like:

```
 - name: test
   include_tasks: test2.yml
   loop: [1,2,3,4]
   when: i != 3
```

But seems the "when" condition only verified once, so all the 4 loops run.

Is the a solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, before making you able to write loops in Ansible, a word of advice. DO NOT WRITE PROGRAMS IN ANSIBLE. Every time you are trying to use loop with big task list, you bring more subtle complexity in your playbooks which will make you suffer later.

Most tasks you want to do with lists, can be done as series of operations on list. E.g. if you have `foo: [1,2,3,4]`, and you want to create directories with those names and send those names to remote server, it's better to write like this:

```
- name: Creating dirs
  file:
    state: directory
    name: '{{ item }}'
  loop: '{{ foo }}'
  when: item != 3

- name: Sending to remote
  uri:
    url: 'http://example.com/{{ item }}'
  loop: '{{ foo }}'
  when: item != 3
```

This code can be maintained and is relatively easy to debug. Now, we here is the thing you want to do with includes:

tasklist.yaml:

```
 - file:
     state: directory
     name: '{{ item }}'
 - uri:
     url: 'http://example.com/{{ item }}'
```

outer tasklist:

```
 - include_tasks: tasklist.yaml
   loop: '{{ foo }}'
   when: item != 3
```

when is evaluated on each run, but you need to put some non-invariant there, f.e. `item` (magic variable for loop to produce).

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

I understand playbook should be simple and clear, not contain complex logic. But we need to do a big loop in order to complete diffcult function. 

The difficulty is my condition is a varible: when: i != 3, not a non-invariant... I wander is there is a way can achieve such goal?